# Infinite loop when using [Authorize] with [Route("xyz")]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, openid-connect

I have a controller action (inside an area, if that matters) that has both the [Authorize] and [Route] attributes, as shown below:

```
[Route("myarea/someaction")]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult SomeAction()
{
    return View("SomeAction");
}
```

I have the application configured to sign in using Azure AD, by using `AddOpenIdConnect()` and the likes (I can provide more detail on that if needed).

When I go to http://localhost:12345/myarea/someaction, it correctly redirects to Azure AD, authenticates the user, and redirects back to http://localhost:12345/myarea/someaction - however, **in an infinite loop**.  It continuously goes through the authentication loop.  If I get in the debugger, `Request.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` returns `false`.

However, if I remove the custom `[Route("myarea/someaction")]` attribute, and use http://localhost:12345/myarea/MyController/SomeAction, it works fine - it authenticates and redirects without the loop.  `Request.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` correctly returns the email address of the authenticated user.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

The app is ASP.NET Core, using .NET Framework 4.6.1, Visual Studio 2017, Windows 10, and IIS Express.

Comment: Just an observation. Did you make the route case sensitive and try?

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I made a test with Asp.Net Core and Word or School Accounts with AAD Domain, it works correctly.

Comment: Thanks @TaoZhou - you're absolutely right - with a fresh project this works as expected.  Now to figure out what's wrong with my real app...

Comment: Share us a demo or detail steps which could reproduce your issue.